# actionPerformed is not being called when buttons are pressed pn my dialog box

Tags: java

When I click the buttons I added for ok and cancel, actionPerformed does not get called
code:

```
void testServerFlags()
{

    dlgEmpty mdlgCreateBot = new dlgEmpty(null);
    
    mdlgCreateBot.show();
    ted=0;
    
}

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import Indicator.cGenIndicator;
import Indicator.cIndicatorUtil;
import MyLib.cLib;

public class dlgEmpty extends JDialog implements ActionListener
{
        Box parPan, topPan, butPan,centerPan;;
                
        public dlgEmpty(JFrame parent) 
          {
                
             super(parent,"Indicators", true);
             
             Container content = getContentPane();
             content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
             
             butPan = Box.createHorizontalBox();
             
             JButton okBut = new JButton("OK");
             okBut.setActionCommand("ok"); 
             butPan.add(okBut, BorderLayout.SOUTH);    
        
             JButton CancelBut = new JButton("Cancel");
             CancelBut.setActionCommand("Cancel"); 
             butPan.add(CancelBut, BorderLayout.SOUTH);    
             content.add(butPan, BorderLayout.SOUTH);                    
             centerPan = Box.createVerticalBox();
              content.add(centerPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);

             pack();
             show();
          }
         boolean isOk=false;
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
          {
              if ("OK".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
                  isOk=true;          
              setVisible(false);
            }  
}
```

Comment: Where do you add the ActionListener to the button?

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character 2) the action command defaults to the text of the button so there is no need to explicitly set it if you want to use the same value 3) It is a better design to have a unique ActionLIstener for each button so you don't even need to worry about the action command. 4) you then need to add each ActionListener to the specific button.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the action command to:

```
okBut.setActionCommand("ok");
```

But are checking for:

```
if ("OK".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
```

This won't match, because the case is different.

Answer (score 0):

setActionCommand only sets the message in the ActionEvent. What you need is addActionListener. I have updated your code.

But the other thing you should know is that there is no need for this. Instead use JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog with a JComponent as the message parameter: It does all the button handling and modal in-line waiting automatically

```
    public dlgEmpty(JFrame parent) 
      {
            
         super(parent,"Indicators", true);
         
         Container content = getContentPane();
         content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         
         butPan = Box.createHorizontalBox();
         
         JButton okBut = new JButton("OK");
         okBut.setActionCommand("ok"); 
         okBut.addActionListener(this); // added this line
         butPan.add(okBut, BorderLayout.SOUTH);    
    
         JButton CancelBut = new JButton("Cancel");
         CancelBut.setActionCommand("Cancel");
         CancelBut.addActionListener(this); 
         butPan.add(CancelBut, BorderLayout.SOUTH); //added this line    
         content.add(butPan, BorderLayout.SOUTH);                    
         centerPan = Box.createVerticalBox();
          content.add(centerPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);

         pack();
         show();
      }
     boolean isOk=false;
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
      {
          if ("OK".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
              isOk=true;          
          setVisible(false);
        }  
}
```